# Force.com IDE: Can't deploy Individual Fields (Option is not coming)

Tags: eclipse, force.com-ide

I have downloaded Eclipse Mars2.0 on two systems. On one system's Eclipse, I am getting the option to select individual fields and on another system's Eclipse, I am not getting the option to select individual fields (here i am getting the option to select object only).

Can anyone explain the reason why?

[image]

Comment: Was the project originally created in the one where you have the option available to you?

Comment: No, I am talking about 2 separate system & I downloaded exact same Eclipse Mars2.0 version and created package separately,

Comment: do you have same version of JAVA in both systems?

Comment: Yes, Tried every version of jre/jdk 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8

Comment: On the system, it is working - we have jre 1.7
On other system, i tried all jre's including 1.7.

Comment: Did you select the same metadata when you downloaded your project for both IDE's and have you tried creating a new project in the one that won't allow you to just download the fields? And BTW, jre 1.7 is the correct one to download.

Comment: Ok, I will try once more with jre 1.7 & let you know.
Thanks @crmprogdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me only reinstallation of Eclipse/jre helped and I used V37.0, cause v38.0 keeps on being buggy.

Also when choosing at least one component the 'package.xml' is created in src folder. You can always manually add fields there as a quickfix.

```
<types>
    <members>*ObjectAPIName*.*FieldAPIName*</members>
    <name>CustomField</name>
</types>
```